# Are there some functions in R programming language for generalized partial linear model?

Tags: r

I want to use generalized partial linear model to fit a data. So are there
some existing functions about GPLM? I'm new about R.

Answer (score 3):

Check out Marlene Muellers work for the package KernGPLM and surrounding at http://www.marlenemueller.de/nspm.html

Generally, [rseek.org](http://rseek.org) is your friend for searching for packages and functionality related to R.